# Command line tool error design

Tags: shell, error-handling

I'm currently working on a command line tool and since this is my first time designing a tool like this I have a few design questions, most notably how to handle a non lethal error.

The tool that I'm working on raises a main server on a configurable port and after that an optional web server on a non configurable port. If we then choose to do this again (while using a different port for the main server) we would obviously get an binding error when try to start up the optional web server.

Since this is a non lethal error (running the webserver is optional) and from UI experience my initial thoughts would be to print out a clear error and carry on with the program. However I've been told that from a scripting stand point print out the error and then existing is better practice.

So what is the better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might also want to consider that people might want to write scripts which expect the invocation to succeed *even if* the webserver is already running.

If you define a default behavior of 'fail if webserver already running', then such scripts will have to parse your error message, or read/understand your return value and figure out that the invocation failed for *this* particular reason (i.e. webserver already running).

Give them a way out of this and introduce a flag (argument) where they can decide which behavior they want. In the absence of the flag, do the safer thing maybe (i.e. error out if webserver is running).

Comment: I understand what you're saying, however overloading the consumer with flags can be confusing IMHO. So in that case why would the "safe" exit be better the a clear message?

Comment: Well, what is the 'safe' default behavior in the absence of a flag probably depends on if/how-much damage occurs if an unfamiliar user invoked the program without the flag. I suggested 'erroring out' as the default because I figured the least damage can occur if it errors out, and therefore nothing runs.